# Как работает приоритетность показа разметки в layout-файле?

Tags: android-layout, framelayout

Ситуация такова: есть разметка FrameLayout, в которой размещены RecyclerView, n-ное количество всяких кнопок и специальная FrameLayout-панель, которая становится видимой при выделении элементов RecyclerView. Столкнулся с проблемой: панель видна только если список пустой или список не достигает ее(ну т.е. по какой-то непонятной мне приоритетности панель находится не поверх списка, а под ним). Тут нужно уточнить тот факт, что эту панель я вставил в качестве самого первого элемента внутри FrameLayout, а вот если перенести ее в самый конец разметки, то я получаю нужный мне результат(панель всегда поверх списка). Поэтому вопрос: как определяется что будет перекрыто чем во FrameLayout? Неужели самый последний его элемент - самый приоритетный? Хотя возможно мне стоит перейти на какую-то другую разметку.

Comment: Из [Документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout?hl=ru) **Сhild views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.** Так что да, самый последний элемент в верстке рисуется поверх предыдущих. Кстати, в документации же есть рекомендация использовать `FrameLayout` только в случаях, когда есть ровно 1 вложенная `View`, а иначе - переходить на другие `ViewGroup`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov понял вас, спасибо большое. Можно было, в принципе, как ответ записать, но ок. И вправду может на CoordinatorLayout перейду.